# Compact with respect to weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

While reviewing some functional analysis we came across this question, which states as follows:

Given $A$, $B$ two separable Banach spaces. The weak topology on $\mathcal{L}(A,B)$ is the one generated by the functions $T:\mathcal{L}(A,B)\rightarrow\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is a scalar field, defined as

$T(f)=\langle f(x),y^*\rangle,$
where $y\in B^*$.

If $B$ is reflexive, then the unit ball $\mathcal{L}_1(A,B)$ in $\mathcal{L}(A,B)$ with the weak topology is compact metrizable.

Maybe I have to modify the Banach-Alaoglu theorem in some way that I havent found, but any help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\{f_j\}$ is a net in $\mathcal L_1(A,B)$. For each $a\in A$, $\{f_j(a)\}$ is a net in the unit ball of $B$. Since $B$ is reflexive, Banach-Alouglu gives you a weak-convergent subnet $\{f_{j_k}\}$. Define $f(a)=\lim_k f_{j_k}(a)$.

Then
$$
\langle f_{j_k}(a),b^*\rangle\to \langle f(a),b^*\rangle,\qquad b^*\in B^*
$$
by definition of the weak topology on $B$.
So $f_{j_k}\to f$ in the weak topology.

Comment: And the fact that it is metrizable follows from the limit?

Comment: In my opinion separability is a crucial property besides reflexivity.

Comment: @Hypershadic50: for the metrizability is where you have to use the separability.

Comment: I see! The Banach-Alaoglu theorem guarantees the metrizability since both spaces are separable right?

Comment: The versions of Banach-Alaoglu I know don't mention metrizability. I don't know what versions you know.